# Import Data from Specific Cells in Word Table to Specific Cells in Excel Workbook start on the first blank row upon each import

Tags: vba, excel

I've got part of this going with a VBA script I found that I slightly modified. I need to import some information from a word table into excel. The problem I'm having is that the script overwrites the first row and I need it to go to the first blank row each time it's used.

Here is what I've got:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iTable As Integer  'table number index
Dim iRow As Long     'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer  'column index in Excel

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
If TableNo = 0 Then
MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
"Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
End If

'Range("A1") = "Table #"
'Range("B1") = "Cell (3,2)"
'Range("C1") = "Cell (4,2)"

For iTable = 1 To TableNo
With .tables(TableNo)
'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells in column B and C
Cells(iTable + 1, "A") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(14, 2).Range.Text)
Cells(iTable + 1, "B") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(2, 2).Range.Text) 'need to post current date
Cells(iTable + 1, "C") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(16, 2).Range.Text)
Cells(iTable + 1, "D") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(15, 2).Range.Text)
Cells(iTable + 1, "E") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(1, 2).Range.Text)
Cells(iTable + 1, "H") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(7, 2).Range.Text)
Cells(iTable + 1, "I") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(8, 2).Range.Text)
Cells(iTable + 1, "S") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(3, 2).Range.Text) 'need to post name of negotiatoe
End With
Next iTable
End With
```

Scott's answer is correct for this. Something strange with the data or something in my file is causing abnormal behavior so below is what is working for me.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iTable As Integer  'table number index
Dim iRow As Long     'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer  'column index in Excel

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
If TableNo = 0 Then
MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
"Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
End If

'Range("A1") = "Table #"
'Range("B1") = "Cell (3,2)"
'Range("C1") = "Cell (4,2)"

For iTable = 1 To TableNo

       Dim lRow As Long
       lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row + 1

        With .tables(TableNo)

            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells in column B and C
            Cells(lRow - 1, "A") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(14, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow - 1, "B") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(2, 2).Range.Text) 'need to post current date
            Cells(lRow - 1, "C") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(16, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow - 1, "D") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(15, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow - 1, "E") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(1, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow - 1, "H") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(7, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow - 1, "I") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(8, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow - 1, "S") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(3, 2).Range.Text) 'need to post name of negotiatoe

        End With

Next iTable
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the next available row in the sheet and write to that row each time with the below modifications to your `For Loop`

```
For iTable = 1 To TableNo

       Dim lRow As Long
       lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row +1

        With .tables(TableNo)

            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells in column B and C
            Cells(lRow, "A") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(14, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow, "B") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(2, 2).Range.Text) 'need to post current date
            Cells(lRow, "C") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(16, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow, "D") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(15, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow, "E") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(1, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow, "H") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(7, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow, "I") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(8, 2).Range.Text)
            Cells(lRow, "S") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(3, 2).Range.Text) 'need to post name of negotiatoe

        End With

Next iTable
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything different. Maybe if I try adding to the first row where the cell in column A is blank.

Comment: @Advancin - My apologies. I forgot to add 1 to the `lRow` to offset the last used row by 1, meaning the next available row. See my edited answer.

Comment: That's working, but it's skipping a row in between each one. So it's pasting the information, then skip row, then paste the information, etc...haha

Comment: did you step-through the code to see why it's doing that? perhaps there are some blank tables in the word document that you do not realize? Either way, stepping through the code line-by-line will surely tell you where the flaw is and then you (or I) can adjust from there. Please do that and let me know what happens, because I cannot test it without data. When doing this pay attention to the value of `lRow` during each loop.

Comment: This is so weird! I've gotten it working by doing `lRow - 1` instead of just `lRow`. Any idea why it would be this is the case?

Comment: @Advancin -  Its hard to say without being able to see the data you are working with.

Comment: Roger that. Thank you for the help with this! I'm marking your answer as correct but will update my original question with my correct solution as well. Have a great one ;)